Euler-Lagrange equation in matrix form
The Euler-Lagrange equation seems fundamental, and mappings or vector functions are prevalent. Thus, I find it peculiar that I haven't seen so far a convenient matrix form of the E-L.
See section "Several functions of several variables with single derivative" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation.
The E-L can be written as
$(\frac{\partial L}{\partial f})^t - \frac{d}{d x} \cdot (\frac{\partial L}{\partial D f})^t = 0$
I'm following the convention that the gradient is the transpose of the Jacobian, e.g., $\frac{df}{dx} = D f = (\nabla f)^t$.
Let's do an example. Consider a mapping $f(x):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. Let's minimize its Dirichlet energy
$L(f) = \frac{1}{2} \int ||D f||_F^2$
The E-L system is:
$0 - \nabla \cdot \nabla f = -\Delta f = 0$
where I used matrix calculus for
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial D f} = D f$

What is the question?

The Euler-Lagrange system you write is incorrect because there are boundary terms that appear when performing the integration by parts. This is one reason why you cannot manipulate differential operators like matrices all the time

@JoshuaTilley, the implied question: how come I haven't seen it, and do you agree.

@whpowell96, I simply wrote wiki's system in a matrix form and gave an example. There's no integration there? Unless you mean that in the general case, with boundary conditions present, the matrix form won't be convenient--or simply wrong. Maybe you have an example?

Getting from the energy functional to the Euler-Lagrange equations requires integration by parts (or Green's first identity) which introduces boundary terms that will induce boundary conditions on the EL equation

To answer your quesiton, you haven't seen it because it's too annoying to work with for people who are new to variational calculus and too simple to deserve a special reference case on Wikipedia for those who are experienced in variational calculus.
